# Error in solution in Types and Programming Languages?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, types-and-programming-languages

I'm reading [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) and trying to understand the solution to exercise 5.2.4 on untyped lambda calculus / Church numerals:

> Define a term for raising one number to the power of another.

The proposed solution says:

> $\textrm{power2} = \lambda m. \lambda n. m~n$

In an attempt to understand how this solution works, I tried it on 0<sup>1</sup> as follows:

$$ \begin{array}{ll}
& \textrm{power2}~c_0~c_1 \\
\rightarrow & c_0~c_1 \\
= & (\lambda s.\lambda z.z)~c_1 \\
\rightarrow & \lambda z.z
\end{array}$$

The result doesn't look like a Church numeral to me. Is it an error in the solution, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Anton is right that you got the order wrong; it's (λm.λn.n m). If (λz.z) doesn't look like a Church numeral to you, (λf.λx.f x) can be "simplified" to (λf.f) via η-conversion.

Comment: η-conversion says that f and λx.(f x) are equivalent. As far as I can tell, that means (λf.f) is equivalent to λx.((λf.f) x), and not (λf.λx.f x). Right?

Comment: Take (λf.f) and replace the f with (λx.f x). If it helps, ((λf.f) x) can be β-reduced to x.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. Replacing the second f in λf.f with (the behaviourally equivalent term) (λx.f x) yields (λf.λx.f x). So λz.z is behaviourally equivalent to (λs.λz.s z) which is the good old c$_1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $power2~m~n$ stands for $m^n$, then it should be

$$power2=λm.λn.n~m$$

Let's try it on $0^1$:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
& power2~c_0~c_1 \\
= & (λm.λn.n~m)~c_0~c_1 \\
\rightarrow & c_1~c_0 \\
= & (λs.λz.s~z)~c_0 \\
\rightarrow & λz.c_0~z \\
= & λz.(λs.λz.z)~z \\
\rightarrow & λs.λz.z \\
= & c_0
\end{array}
$$
Works fine.

Let's try it on $1^0$:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
& power2~c_1~c_0 \\
= & (λm.λn.n~m)~c_1~c_0 \\
\rightarrow & c_0~c_1 \\
= & (λs.λz.z)~c_1 \\
\rightarrow & λz.z
\end{array}
$$

Wait, we should have got $c_1$.

Although syntactically $λz. z$ is different from it, but it has the same behavior as $c_1$.
In fact, you can use the function $equal$ (ex. 5.2.7) to prove it:
$$
equal = λm. λn.~and~(iszro~(m~prd~n))~~~(iszro~(n~prd~m))
$$

By the way, another form of the power function, given in the solution to this exercise have the arguments swapped:

$$power1 = λm. λn. m~(times~n)~c_1$$.

Comment: *"What you got is $0^1 = 0$"* $-$ No, 0 ($c_0$) is represented by $\lambda s. \lambda z. z$, and not $\lambda z.z$. Assuming I *did* swap the arguments, my question still stands, though slightly reformulated: Why doesn't $0^1$ result in $c_0$?

Comment: Would you edit your question to reflect that, please?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the first thing I checked was the [errata](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/errata.txt) which indeed says that the arguments are swapped. So I tried both ways before even posting the question. What puzzles me is that in one of the cases I get $\lambda z.z$ which doesn't even look like a church numeral to me.

Comment: I addressed this issue with λz.z in the last part of my answer.